# Hibernate 4 & Weblogic Connections

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, weblogic

I have established connections in Oracle Weblogic and I tried to include those connection through datasource I am getting below error message.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-

    3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory >
      <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/TestDB</property>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
      <mapping class="org.axe.gre.tools.beans.Country"/>
     </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

**config.xml**

```
<jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>TestDB</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/TestDB-3376-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jdbc-system-resource>
```

**Error Message**

```
<pre>

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.axe.gre.tools.web.CountryDetail.getCountryList(CountryDetail.java:23)
    at org.axe.gre.tools.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:88)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/TestDB]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp.env.TestDB in /app/webapp/ServletProject/21670082.; remaining name '/comp/env/TestDB'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1180)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:146)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:253)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:426)
    at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
</pre>
```

Comment: What is the JNDI name inside of `jdbc/TestDB-3376-jdbc.xml`? You probably need just `TestDB` and can drop `java:comp/env/` in `hibernate.cfg.xml`  since Weblogic automatically adds `java:` to the container

Comment: I have created this JDBC connection in Oracle Weblogic and TestDB-3376-jdbc.xml is auto generated. In TestDB-3376-jdbc.xml we have connection information like Id, Password etc.

Comment: I understand, I am saying you should try `<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">TestDB</property>` instead. Get rid of java:comp/env/